# How to prefill address field forms?

Tags: 7, entities

I've been using the [Prepopulate](http://drupal.org/project/prepopulate) module for a while, and it works really well. It can't prefill an [addressfield](http://drupal.org/project/addressfield) type field, though.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add something like this to your hook_form_alter() or hook_form_FORM_ID_alter():

```
  $form['field_address'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['#address']['country'] = 'US';
  $form['field_address'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['#address']['locality'] = 'Livermore';
  $form['field_address'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['#address']['administrative_area'] = 'CA';
  $form['field_address'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['#address']['postal_code'] = '94551';
```

Comment: where would one put this code? Thanks...

Comment: @mototribe Did you see the answer provided by pinueve above?

Answer (score 2):

Just as addition to MotoTribe's answer. I had to prefill some fields of the registration form and used the YOUR_THEME_hook_form_FORM_ID_alter() function in my template.php.

The fields are custom and the way to go for me was to set a default value:

```
$form['field_custom_field_name'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']['#default_value']
```

Maybe this helps someone out.

Comment: Did you see the answer provided by pinueve above?

Answer (score 0):

D7 solution by custom module. This is to prepopulate current user address_field when creating a new node. Add user address_field field, name it user_address, then make a custom module with the following code, replace CAPTIAL LETTERS   as needed.

function YOURMUDULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

/* Check to see if the form alter function is actually running */
/* dsm($form); **/

```
/* Only do this for a new, not-yet updated entityform -NB might need a 'return' here */
if (!isset($form['#entity']->is_new)) {

    //Ensure, we're updating field info on the correct entity type
    if ($form_id == 'CONTENTYPE_node_form') {

       if (!isset($form['#entity']->is_new)) {

        /* function load user data from field_user_address */
          global $user;
          $current_user = user_load($user->uid);
          $current_user_country = $current_user->field_user_address[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['country'];
          $current_user_estate = $current_user->field_user_address[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['administrative_area'];
          $current_user_city = $current_user->field_user_address[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['locality'];
          $current_user_locality = $current_user->field_user_address[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['dependent_locality'];


          /*  dsm(user_load($user->uid));     */       

          $form['field_CONTENTYPE_FIELD'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['#address']['country'] = $current_user_country;
          $form['field_CONTENTYPE_FIELD'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['#address']['administrative_area'] = $current_user_estate;
          $form['field_CONTENTYPE_FIELD'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['#address']['locality'] = $current_user_city;
          $form['field_CONTENTYPE_FIELD'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['#address']['dependent_locality'] = $current_user_locality;

          }
      }

  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I do not why first two lines of code are "out of bound". Ofcourse you'll need on node an address field.